# Dirty property in access vba isn't case sensitive

Tags: vba, ms-access

If I change only one letter in text box from upper to lower, access don't set dirty property to true. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Don't make variable or control names that duplicate built-in object, property or function names in Access. If you have a control named `dirty`, it can interfere with how the form `Dirty` property works. If you have a control named `date`, all instances of the `Date` function will display in lower case. The common fix: rename the `dirty` control to `txtDirty`. Search for "access hungarian notation" for handy prefixes you can use to help resolve this problem (just don't go overboard).

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please edit your question and add some more specific details on what and how you are trying to and what the problem is. Please also consider reading [ask] again.

Comment: @Mike why did you vote "Requires Editing" in [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/22273116)? Yes it's a hard to understand question, but how should any user in [Help and Improve review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper) edit this question to make it better? The only one able to do this is the op, thus it's either Unsalvageable or Looks OK. Sadly the Help and Improve queue is flooded by posts wrongly voted "Requires editing" [most of which are then just skipped.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346002/)

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla same for you, see above ;-)

Comment: @Selaron: The question is understandable to someone familiar with Access forms.